# Write JS variable containing "</script>" string into Django HTML template

Tags: javascript, django

How would I write the following Python object to a JavaScript variable in a template:

```
{"foo": {"bar": "</script>"}, "baz": 1}
```

The above object would be written to a JS variable in an HTML template. That variable would then have two properties, `foo` and `baz`. The `foo` property would evaluate to an object having a property `bar`. A problem is that the `</script>` tag closes the parent `<script>` element (in the HTML template) prematurely.

Comment: What are you doing right now and what result are you seeing?

Comment: did you try escaping it: {"foo": {"bar": "<\/script>"}, "baz": 1}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to spectras.

In Python (2.7):

```
js = json.dumps({"foo": {"bar": "</script>", "url":"one/two/three"}, "baz": 1})
```

In the Django (1.7) template:

```
<script>
var data = JSON.parse('{{ js|escapejs }}');
</script>
```

Comment: Couldn't you drop the call to `replace` and change `|safe` to `|escapejs`?